# Turn a regual user into a admin (use sudo)

Tags: sudo, opensuse, yast

when installing OpenSUSE on my system, I had made the root user be four the standard user and now I want to get rid (or lock) the root user account and use `sudo` for administrative task. I used Yast control center to add the user and the (already existing) home directory. So I logout and try to use `sudo` with zypper command and it ask for the root password and not mine. I had tried to work with the sudo utility in Yast program and that did not work.

So how would I fix this issue.

Comment: You need to configure sudo to allow use by groups or specific users, and make sure either your regular user is listed or a group they are a member of is listed as allowed.

Comment: I have my user account with the users and wheel group, and the aias is %root. Or in simple terms `%whell ALL = (%root) NOPASSWORD:ALL` and it stills ask me for a root password.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the sudoers file and I had to remove two line one being `ALL ALL = (ALL) ALL`.

Extension:
It was a default setting in openSUSE. I was reading the the sudoers file comments and under a part of the document, the files says to deletes two rows of text witch fixed the problem. (I don't exactly remember the two lines, except for the ALL line.)

Comment: It seems to me a "magician answer", I suggest to show also the causality chain, not only the result.

Comment: It was a default setting in openSUSE. I was reading the the sudoers file comments and under a part of the document, the files says to deletes two rows of text witch fixed the problem. (I don't exactly remember the two lines, except for the ALL line.)

Comment: Not as another comment, edit it into your post. So.